# Level curve of function that passes through given point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a function $f(x,y)= 16-x^2-y^2$ that passes through the point $(2\sqrt(2),\sqrt(2))$ . How do I find out the equation of level curve?
I dont have any idea . Pls provide hints.

What I am doing is putting the values in the function which gives $f(x,y)$ as $6$. So my level curve (I am not sure) should be

$6=16-x^2-y^2$
Which gives $x^2+y^2=10$
Which is wrong

Comment: According to me it should be $x^2+y^2=10$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug the coordinates of the point in your function to get $f(x,y)=6$

Thus the level curve is $$16-x^2-y^2=6$$ 
Or $$x^2+y^2=10$$ which is a circle centered at the origin with radius $R=\sqrt {10}$

Comment: But sir the answer given is $x^2+y^2=1$

Comment: $x^2+y^2=1$ is not correct because it does not pass through the point.